# Android ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, email, android-intent

i wanna make an action that the android app can send an email, and the email subject and body already fill with the edittext from the android app.
here's my code

```
Intent ii = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
ii.setType("text/plain");
    EditText txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    EditText txtAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
    EditText txtLatitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
    EditText txtLongitude = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);

ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, txtName.getText().toString());
ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtAddress.getText().toString());
ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtLatitude.getText().toString());
ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txtLongitude.getText().toString());

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ii, "Share via"));
```

The subject is fine, but the body email is only fill with the last content(txtLongitude).

please tell me what to do.
Gratz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make one string from the 3 EditTexts, then set it as an extra. For Example:

```
String body = txtName.getText().toString() + txtLatitude.getText().toString() + txtLongitude.getText().toString()
ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

You'll probably also want to add some things like new line characters to format the text.

Comment: thanks, it's working.
yeah just like what you thought, i wanna make it with new line.
how do i do that?

Comment: You can add a "\n" string after each of the texts.

Answer (score 1):

> The subject is fine, but the body email is only fill with the last content(txtLongitude).

That is because you keep overriding the same `EXTRA_TEXT` extra. Call `putExtra()` for `EXTRA_TEXT` *once*, with the *complete body* of the email you want to send.